# Передача имени ссылки в php файл

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется множество ссылок вида

```
<a href="nameOfFile.php">name1</a>
<a href="nameOfFile.php">name2</a>
<a href="nameOfFile.php">name3</a>
<a href="nameOfFile.php">name4</a>
.....
```

Эти ссылки являются столбцом таблицы и ведут на один и тот же файл, который является особой формой.
Мне нужно в файле на который они ведут (nameofFile.php) получить имя ссылки (допустим name1), на которую нажал пользовать при переходе, чтобы вывести данные по этому названию (name1). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. С js особо не знаком

Вывод данных ссылок:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields=count($row); $i++) {
            if($i==0){
                echo '<TD><a href="nameOfFile.php">' . $row[$i] . '</a></TD>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<TD>' . $row[$i] . '</TD>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: почему бы вам не передать это самое имя в качестве параметра, что бы ссылки были вида `nameOfFile.php?name=name1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить "имя ссылки" напрямую в том виде, в каком говорите вы - невозможно (без JS по крайней мере). Но ничего не мешает добавить к ссылкам еще один параметр и передавать через него name:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields=count($row); $i++) {
    if($i==0){
        echo '<TD><a href="nameOfFile.php?name=' . urlencode($row[$i]) . '">' . $row[$i] . '</a></TD>';
    } echo {
        '<TD>' . $row[$i] . '</TD>';
    }
}
```

А в nameOfFile.php получаете этот параметр таким образом

```
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь скорый ответ, но дело в том, что я заранее не знаю имя ссылки. Они у меня выводятся через массив (добавил описание в вопросе), как быть в этом случае?

Comment: А где сами адреса ссылок? в показанном вами коде нет ссылок, по которым будет осуществляться переход на .php-файл

Comment: <a href="nameOfFile.php">' . $row[$i] . '</a>

Comment: @МаксимПетров поправил ответ